# Buck step down convertor uses a lot of current?

Tags: buck, converter

I have a DC-DC buck step down converter module LM2596 voltage regulator
set to supply 3.0 volts to an atomic clock using a 8 Ah 12 V battery. The clock normally uses 2 AA batteries.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-Buck-Step-Down-Converter-Module-LM2596-Voltage-Regulator-Led-Voltmeter-M3/301724177038?epid=10003955778&hash=item464029928e:g:bAwAAOSwdsFUNdsC

The battery started out at 12.07 V. After 10 days, it's at 8.45 Volts.

It does seem like it should not have dropped that much.

It claims static power: 20 ma. Does that mean power used?

The converter has a digital voltage readout. Does it use a lot of current?

Comment: It should be quite obvious that if a device has 3-digit digital readout with 7-segment LEDs, it should draw quite measurable current. Assume 1 mA per LED, and all 21 segments can easily eat 20 mA from input power source.

Comment: You should post this question to the eBay seller.  EE.SE isn't his volunteer application support.

Comment: Rather than guessing, *measure* the current.  Also realize you've killed your battery, potentially permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have bought a converter that uses at least 20mA, regardless of what load you put on it.  Some part of that will be driving the voltage display.

Roughly speaking, that converter would drain an 8AH battery in 400 hours, or 16 days, even if nothing else was connected.

Comment: Thanks. I found a switch that turns the led display off. That should extend my runtime. :-)

Comment: The display and A/D chip are likely fed by a linear regulator too.

Comment: @Jack Creasey How would that apply to my situation?

Comment: @fixit7 They draw constant power not related to the DC-DC convertor task. I imagine your display has at least 11 segments on for 3V. Even turning off the display may not remove as much of the current as you think. The LM2596 alone requires a quiescent current of 5mA+ in addition to requiring 3A pulse current, and then whatever chip and linear regulator is used for the display.

Comment: Good info. It seems like converting 12 V to 3 V is not very efficient with what I have. I did notice one of the components got pretty warm, so a lot of loss is through heat.